# Issues with using Microsoft Graph with typescript

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VSCode Extension. Part of the functionality is to get TodoTaskList from MS Graph. I'm currently using TypeScript version 4.3.5 and using the docs at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings/, https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#2-create-a-client-instance and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

I am able to get accessToken using VS Code Authentication API and here's the code I wrote to get the TodoTaskList. I'm importing getMyTasks in extension.ts and passing the accessToken there.

```
import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
import { AuthenticationProvider } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
require('isomorphic-fetch');
import * as MicrosoftGraph from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types";

export async function getMyTasks(accessToken: string) {
    class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
        /**
         * This method will get called before every request to the msgraph server
         * This should return a Promise that resolves to an accessToken (in case of success) or rejects with error (in case of failure)
         * Basically this method will contain the implementation for getting and refreshing accessTokens
         */
        public async getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
            return accessToken; 
        }
    }
    const options = {
        authProvider: new MyAuthenticationProvider(), // An instance created from previous step
    };
    const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(options);
    try {
        let taskList = await client.api("/me/todo/lists").get();
        let tasks: [MicrosoftGraph.TodoTaskList] = taskList.value;
        for (let task of tasks) {
            console.log(task.displayName);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Here's my dependencies from package.json:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^1.41.0",
        "@types/glob": "^7.1.3",
        "@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.53.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
        "eslint": "^7.9.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.6",
        "mocha": "^8.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.0.2",
        "vscode-test": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^2.2.1",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0"
    }
```

I'm getting the following errors:
[image: List of Errors]

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/124, it need `lib: ["dom"]` in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is acknowledged here: [github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/124](http://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/124)

Fix: It needs `lib: ["es6", "dom"]` in tsconfig.json

Huge thanks to @[yume-chan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179747/yume-chan)